# How do I delay the iOS keyboard from popping up?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, keyboard

So...I have my UIScrollView move up when the keyboard pops up, and that works...except that they UIScrollView and the keyboard don't come up in sync...first, the keyboard pops up, then the UIScrollView.

I know there's a way to delay the keyboard so that it shows up at the same time that the view scrolls up; how do I do that?? I tried this in viewDidLoad:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

...and I have this as well:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4000 target:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

(I know, 4000 is a huge number, but I wanted to make sure there was a delay!!)

Also, when I dismiss the keyboard, rather than a smooth scroll, the UIScrollView just plain jumps back into place instead of easing down...is there a reasonable way to take care of that?

---

UPDATE:

Got it...thanks to Steven Fisher for helping me on the right path...I moved everything to keyboardWillShow, and added the following code:

```
[UIScrollView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIScrollView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIScrollView setAnimationDuration:.32];
[UIScrollView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:NO];
```

Somehow this also solved my "jump" problem when the keyboard goes away! woohoo!

Comment: Your working this backwards. You should be timing the scroll views offset change to the keyboards animation. And it's hard to say why it "jumps back" without seeing some related code.

Comment: Okay, then how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that apple documentation given for this kind situation.

```
// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
        name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
         selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
         name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}



// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
 {
   NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
   CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
   // Your application might not need or want this behavior.
   CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
   aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
   if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);
    [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
   }
  }



// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{  
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

Comment: That's EXACTLY the code I use, but again, the keyboard and the scrollview don't go up at the same time: first the keyboard, THEN the scrollview. How do I get them both to come up at the exact same time?

Comment: Hook into `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`, not `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`.

Comment: Also: This was not part of the question, but if you're trying to duck the keyboard and support rotation you should make sure to never show it from `viewWillAppear`, where the view coordinates have not been set up. Instead, use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_mainqueue(),^{[field becomeFirstResponder];});` in `viewWillAppear`. That'll make sure the coordinates have been updated for the current orientation, but it'll still look seamless. (If you're not letting the device rotate, don't worry about this.)

Answer (score 0):

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
 }

 - (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  // To avoid keyboard hides the view
  CGRect frame = self.view.bounds; 
if (capitalTextField.enabled ==YES) 
{
     if ([notification name]== UIKeyboardDidShowNotification ) 
     {

        frame.origin.y += 200;
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
     }
     else
     {
        frame.origin.y -= 200;
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES]; 
     }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the below code will delay pop up

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
[textField becomefirstresponder];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```